# How can I make a field public in AWS Amplify graphql schema?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am writing an AWS amplify graphql schema for a set of users. I want the usernames to be public (so anyone can search and find users by username) and the user's info (descriptions, etc) to be private (only followers can see).

I know how to use `@auth` to setup the private data, but how can I make usernames public?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this PR will implement this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/pull/1916

Answer (score 0):

You can allow public schema access by ApiKey but have restricted fields using         @aws_iam decorator

```
type Post @aws_api_key {
    id: ID!
    author: String
    title: String
    content: String
    url: String
    ups: Int!
    downs: Int!
    version: Int!
    restrictedContent: String!
    @aws_iam
}
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/1